# Countdown timer from a date (Date is loaded from database)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, countdown

I was wondering if there is a way to create a countdown timer from a date without the use of jquery ajax? I know a little knowledge of javascript and some c#. I have the tools of Visual Studio 2017 AJAX Extension if that helps.

I would like to display the countdown timer that counts down from the date in real time (partial refresh of the page).

I do know that i have to use update panels and script manager. But what is the c# code itself? Do I store it in a session variable?

The timer starts on page load.

Comment: I've never done it but I think you can create a timer on a page with pure javascript. If you know the date you can hard code everything in js and done. (Btw, do you want a timer `from` a date or `to` a date?) If you have to get the date from a db, is that done? Break down the problem and start searching for answers to each part. I'm sure every part has been answered here.

Comment: I need the timer to to be server-based. Or is that the same? I want the countdown from the date. For example, i have "24 hours" left till date x.

Answer (score 0):

As a base you could do this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018, 08, 10); // your date from the db.
TimeSpan dt2 = dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
// add the time remaining to a label.
lblDateDiff.Text = "Time's up in "
    + dt2.Days.ToString() + " days, "
    + dt2.Hours.ToString() + " hours, "
    + dt2.Minutes.ToString() + " minutes "
    + dt2.Seconds.ToString() + " seconds.";
```

That won't count down like a timer but if it's on Page_Load it will refresh with every load.

If JS is an option, you could add the date to the page and use the moment.js library: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/tonow/

For a timer, I'm not sure but I doubt you can do it with code-behind, unless you're using a `polling` mechanism like [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). JS's setInterval() would be the easiest.

Comment: that is so much help! Thank you. Yes i would like to do it in the code behind page and put it in a label.Text. But the problem is i do not know how to implement JS into code behind page. how could i implemnent the code above in a setInterval()?

Comment: Please upvote if the answer has helped and start a new question.